# Mapping to POCOs with top-level dictionary from Postgres jsonb column

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I have a .NET Core 3.1 application using EF Core and a Postgres database. In the database I have one jsonb column that I now want to map to a well-defined set of classes in EF Core.

The content of the jsonb column looks like the following:

```
{
    "entry1": {
        "name": "entry1",
        "contents": {
            "entry1.1": {
                "name": "entry1.1"
            },
            "entry1.2": {
                "name": "entry1.2",
                "contents": {
                    "entry1.2.1": {
                        "name": "entry1.2.1"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

At the top level it is a dictionary mapping strings to entries. Each entry has a name and can have contents, which is again a dictionary mapping strings to entries.

```
public class Entry
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Entry> contents { get; set; }
}
```

The jsonb column itself is defined on a table like this:

```
public class MyTable {
    [Column(TypeName = "jsonb")]
    public Dictionary<string, Entry> Entries { get; set; }
}
```

The problem with this now is that it simply doesn't work. When I fetch an entry from the database with EF Core, the "Entries" property does contain indeed a dictionary with a single key "entry1", but the value of that key is an empty `Entry` object (name and contents are both null).

The [Npgsql documentation on mapping jsonb columns to POCOs](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/json.html?tabs=data-annotations%2Cpoco) doesn't explain how to handle dictionaries in this case. I couldn't find any examples with a top-level dictionary in the jsonb column, so I'm not entirely sure I'm doing this right.

How can I wire this up correctly so that my jsonb column gets mapped to a dictionary of Entry objects?

Comment: From my current experience with Npgsql, it seems the mapping has to be fairly concrete. Meaning your POCO's will have to match the keys you provide in the json. 

If it were me, i would probably read the JSON in as a whole string and then parse it with a helper/service. It seems like the trouble would come in the cascading of your "entry" objects.

Comment: @GingerNinja it works out of the box if the property is a list or the Entry class directly, only the Dictionary doesn't work. I'm not sure if this is simply one case EF Core npgsql didn't implement, or if I'm doing something wrong here. I found how to manually define serialization just now, and it works even with the recursive links between the Entry objects. But as far as I understand this version of doing things is more limited (e.g. no query support)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following seems to work well:

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var createCtx = new BlogContext())
        {
            createCtx.Database.EnsureDeleted();
            createCtx.Database.EnsureCreated();

            createCtx.Blogs.Add(new Blog
            {
                Entries = new Dictionary<string, Entry>
                {
                    { "bla", new Entry { Foo = "foo1" }}
                }
            });

            createCtx.SaveChanges();
        }

        using var ctx = new BlogContext();

        var results = ctx.Blogs.Single();
        Console.WriteLine(results.Entries["bla"].Foo);
    }
}

public class BlogContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }

    static ILoggerFactory ContextLoggerFactory
        => LoggerFactory.Create(b => b.AddConsole().AddFilter("", LogLevel.Information));

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        => optionsBuilder
            .UseNpgsql(@"Host=localhost;Database=test;Username=npgsql_tests;Password=npgsql_tests")
            .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
            .UseLoggerFactory(ContextLoggerFactory);
}

public class Blog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "jsonb")]
    public Dictionary<string, Entry> Entries { get; set; }
}

public class Entry
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

In the database:

```
test=# select * from "Blogs"
test-# ;
 Id | Name |         Entries          
----+------+--------------------------
  1 |      | {"bla": {"Foo": "foo1"}}
(1 row)
```

Comment: That's weird, it looks pretty much exactly like what I was trying to do, I can't see any relevant difference right now. I'll have to compare this more carefully with my own version to see what I did differently. Thanks for providing a full self-contained example, that will be really helpful to experiment with.